# MySQL: Aggregating counts

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, aggregate

I'm trying to find how many companies had sales in a specific segment. I've managed to get a count of the sales entries (5), but I can't seem to aggregate by the product segment as well. Please see this simplification:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/685cb/1

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`company` text, `sales` int, `segment` text)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`company`, `segment`, `sales`)
VALUES
    ('ACME',10,100),
    ('ACME',11,100),
    ('HAL',10,25),
    ('HAL',13,25),
    ('GEN',11,50)
;

SELECT COUNT(company) AS companies,
CASE 
    WHEN segment IN (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
    THEN 'Product segment A'
    WHEN segment IN (20, 21, 22)
    THEN 'Product segment B'
    WHEN segment IN (30)
    THEN 'Product segment C'
    END AS grp, SUM(sales) AS sum_sales
FROM Table1
WHERE
       (company LIKE '%ACME%'
     OR company LIKE '%HAL%'
     OR company LIKE '%GEN%'
    )
AND
    segment IN (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ,16, 20, 21, 22, 30)
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY grp
;
```

The goal is to get "companies" to show 3, as there are three companies that had sales in segment A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `distinct` modifier in the `count` function to get the number of **different** entries:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT company) AS companies,
-- Here -----^
CASE 
    WHEN segment IN (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
    THEN 'Product segment A'
    WHEN segment IN (20, 21, 22)
    THEN 'Product segment B'
    WHEN segment IN (30)
    THEN 'Product segment C'
    END AS grp, SUM(sales) AS sum_sales
FROM Table1
WHERE
       (company LIKE '%ACME%'
     OR company LIKE '%HAL%'
     OR company LIKE '%GEN%'
    )
AND
    segment IN (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ,16, 20, 21, 22, 30)
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY grp
;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/685cb/5/0)**

Comment: D'oh, it always seems so easy when someone is able to accurately answer it. Great, thanks!